# Creating Model for Cassandra using Phantom DSL

Tags: scala, phantom-dsl

I am reading [this piece of source code](https://github.com/iamthiago/cassandra-phantom/blob/c23b6decbcf5eb72784d432fba98e9a4288056b2/src/main/scala/com/cassandra/phantom/modeling/model/GenericSongsModel.scala).

This looks good but what if instead of artist, the field was "artists" where artists was an `list<text>` in cassandra?

I found this article which talks about using ListColumn

https://github.com/websudos/phantom/wiki/Collection-columns

but I am not sure how will you define index on the ListColumn

```
  object genre extends ListColumn(this) with Index[List[String]]
```

The line above does not compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware you can only do contains queries with secondary indexes on Set columns, not List.

Here's what you do: `object genre extends SetColumn[Table, Record, Int](this) with Index[Set[Int]]`. The 2 types `Table` and `Record` have to match what you provided when you extended `CassandraTable` just above, like this:

```
class MyTable extends CassandraTable[MyTable, MyRecord] {
  object genre extends SetColumn[MyTable, MyRecord, Int](this) with Index[Set[Int]]
}
```

Hope this makes sense. Careful with `ListColumn` too, all collection columns need the `TableType` and `RecordType` arguments.

**Update**

In more recent versions of phantom, you don't need to provide the type of the table and the record. Just do the following:

```
class MyTable extends CassandraTable[MyTable, MyRecord] {
  object genre extends SetColumn[Int](this) with Index[Set[Int]]
}
```

Look at [this test](https://github.com/websudos/phantom/blob/develop/phantom-dsl/src/test/scala/com/websudos/phantom/builder/query/db/specialized/IndexedCollectionsTest.scala) for examples on using indexed collections, and then at [this table](https://github.com/websudos/phantom/blob/develop/phantom-dsl/src/test/scala/com/websudos/phantom/tables/IndexedCollectionsTable.scala) for an example on how to define such tables.

Regards.